# elif not working

Tags: shell-script

I am running a cardano node wich includes an automint solution. Im rewriting a script and i got it working. But there is a problem with a particular part of the script. This part of the elif should check if there is a incoming transaction of 8000000 and check if there is a metadata file in the folders metadata3-1 metadata3. If the transaction of 8000000 is ok and there is a file in both folders it should go to the "then" part of the script if there is not a file in one of the folders or the transaction is higher or lower then it should go to the "else" part. For some reason its not doing that. Can somebody help me with that?

```
 elif [ ${utxo_balance} == 8000000 ] || [ $(ls "metadata3-1/" | wc -l) >= 1 ] || [ $(ls "metadata3/" | wc -l) >= 1 ] ;
        then
        ###1 NFT version 1+2###
        echo "Sending NFT..." >> $log
        numberCompleted=$(( numberCompleted+1 ))
        POLICYID=$(cardano-cli transaction policyid --script-file $scriptPath)
            metadata_file=$(ls metadata3/ | sort -R | tail -1)
            metadata_file2=$(ls metadata3-1/ | sort -R | tail -1)
            name=$(echo ${metadata_file} | awk '{ print substr( $0, 1, length($0)-5 ) }')
            name2=$(echo ${metadata_file2} | awk '{ print substr( $0, 1, length($0)-5 ) }')
            head -n -3 ./metadata3/${metadata_file} > ./metadata3/metatemp.json ; mv ./metadata3/metatemp.json ./metadata3/${metadata_file}
            tail -n +4 ./metadata3-1/${metadata_file2} > ./metadata3-1/metatemp2.json ; mv ./metadata3-1/metatemp2.json ./metadata3-1/${metadata_file2}
            cat ./tempfiles/policy.json ./metadata3/${metadata_file} ./tempfiles/komma.json ./metadata3-1/${metadata_file2} > ./tempfiles/meta.json
        amountToSendUser=2200000
        amountToDonate=2800000
        amountToSendProfit=3000000
            currentSlot=$(cardano-cli query tip --mainnet | jq -r '.slot')
            cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
                --fee 0 \
                ${tx_in} \
                --tx-out ${in_addr}+${amountToSendUser}+"1 $POLICYID.${name}"+"1 $POLICYID.${name2}" \
                --tx-out ${profitAddr}+${amountToSendProfit} \
        --tx-out ${donationAddr}+${amountToDonate} \
        --mint="1 $POLICYID.${name}"+"1 $POLICYID.${name2}" \
        --minting-script-file $scriptPath \
        --metadata-json-file ./tempfiles/meta.json \
                --invalid-hereafter $(( ${currentSlot} + 10000)) \
                --out-file tx3.tmp >> $log
            fee=$(cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee \
                --tx-body-file tx3.tmp \
                --tx-in-count 1 \
                --tx-out-count 3 \
                --mainnet \
                --witness-count 2 \
                --byron-witness-count 0 \
                --protocol-params-file protocol3.json | awk '{ print $1 }') >> $log
        fee=${fee%" Lovelace"}
            amountToSendUser=$((${amountToSendUser} - ${fee}))
            cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
                --fee ${fee} \
                ${tx_in} \
                --tx-out ${in_addr}+${amountToSendUser}+"1 $POLICYID.${name}"+"1 $POLICYID.${name2}" \
                --tx-out ${profitAddr}+${amountToSendProfit} \
        --tx-out ${donationAddr}+${amountToDonate} \
        --mint="1 $POLICYID.${name}"+"1 $POLICYID.${name2}" \
                --minting-script-file $scriptPath \
        --metadata-json-file ./tempfiles/meta.json \
                --invalid-hereafter $(( ${currentSlot} + 10000)) \
                --out-file tx3.raw >> $log
            cardano-cli transaction sign \
                --signing-key-file $paymentSignKeyPath \
            --signing-key-file $policySignKeyPath \
                --tx-body-file tx3.raw \
                --out-file tx3.signed \
                --mainnet >> $log
            cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file tx3.signed --mainnet >> $log
        rm ./metadata3/${metadata_file}
        rm ./metadata3-1/${metadata_file2}
        else
        echo ${utxo_balance} >> $log
        echo "Refund Initiated..." >> $log
        currentSlot=$(cardano-cli query tip --mainnet | jq -r '.slot')
            cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
                --fee 0 \
               ${tx_in} \
                --tx-out ${in_addr}+${utxo_balance} \
                --invalid-hereafter $(( ${currentSlot} + 1000)) \
                --out-file tx3.tmp >> $log
            fee=$(cardano-cli transaction calculate-min-fee \
                --tx-body-file tx3.tmp \
                --tx-in-count 1 \
                --tx-out-count 1 \
                --mainnet \
                --witness-count 1 \
                --byron-witness-count 0 \
                --protocol-params-file protocol3.json | awk '{ print $1 }') >> $log
            fee=${fee%" Lovelace"}
            amountToSendUser=$(( ${utxo_balance}-${fee} ))
        echo ${amountToSendUser} >> $log
            cardano-cli transaction build-raw \
                --fee ${fee} \
                ${tx_in} \
                --tx-out ${in_addr}+${amountToSendUser} \
                --invalid-hereafter $(( ${currentSlot} + 1000)) \
                --out-file tx3.raw >> $log
            cardano-cli transaction sign \
                --signing-key-file $paymentSignKeyPath \
                --tx-body-file tx3.raw \
                --out-file tx3.signed \
                --mainnet >> $log
            cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file tx3.signed --mainnet >> $log
        fi
```

Comment: You have 92 lines here, and given it starts with `elif`, it's not even a complete example that anyone could run. Look at the full script you have, then pick the part where the problem is, and remove everything else, while keeping it a complete script that runs. E.g. if the issue is with the `elif` condition, the commands inside the branch probably don't matter, and could be replaced with just `echo running elif branch` or so. Similarly for everything outside the if statement. Then fix your indentation, and then run the script through [shellcheck.net](shellcheck.net).

Comment: The problem is in this part:

elif [ ${utxo_balance} -eq 8000000 ] || [ $(ls "metadata3-1/" | wc -l) -ge 1 ] || [ $(ls "metadata3/" | wc -l) -ge 1 ] ;
         then

If one of these is not true it should not go to the "then" part but to the "else" part of the script. I know for certain that one of the folders(metadata3) is empty so the 3th command in the line is false

Answer (score 5):

There was no need to post anything more than

```
elif [ ${utxo_balance} == 8000000 ] || [ $(ls "metadata3-1/" | wc -l) >= 1 ] || [ $(ls "metadata3/" | wc -l) >= 1 ] ;
```

Terrible question. It is not even clear from your description what kind of problem it is, syntax or unexpected behaviour. Not even an error message.

### wrong relation operators

Nonetheless it is clear that you are using the wrong operators.

Arithmetic expressions (like your `>=`) are allowed in `((4>=3))` only but not in `[   ]`. The `test` command (`[` is just an alias for that, it is not shell grammar) has a different syntax (conditional expressions):

> arg1 OP arg2
> OP is one of -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.

So you need:

```
elif [ ${utxo_balance} -eq 8000000 ] || [ $(ls "metadata3-1/" | wc -l) -ge 1 ] || [ $(ls "metadata3/" | wc -l) -ge 1 ] ;
```

### wrong logic operators

Your condition is

```
elif A || B || C
```

so if condition A **or** condition B **or** condition C is true then the whole expression becomes true.

The description disagrees:

> If the transaction of 8000000 is ok **and** there is a file in both folders it should go to the "then" part

so the code must be

```
elif A && B && C
```

Comment: im not getting an error on it. But then it tries to send out nfts wich are minted with this script but because there is only 1 file in 1 folder it cant send because its not complete. So i get an error on sending.

Comment: I changed the ++ to -eq and the >= to -ge But still having the same problem. it still goes to the "then" part what it should not do.

Comment: @Koelie1984 I found the other problem and extended the answer.